# Are the changes of a write transaction in ClientA immediately visible to a ClientB read, started after COMMIT?

Tags: postgresql

We are observing some behaviours/errors in some of our workflows, related to the consistency and visiblity of a Postgres write transaction, followed by a read. One of our developers offered an explanation, but I could not find any search results documenting the proposed reasoning.

Given a single Postgres 10.3 host, the following operations take place:

1. ClientA performs a successful write transaction
2. After the COMMIT, an external notification is emitted
3. ClientB reacts to external notification and performs a read, only to find that the UPDATE transaction changes are not visible

The explanation that was proposed is that two postgres client connections on different threads don't have a guaranteed view snapshot and may not immediately observe the write transaction update after the commit. But from what I have read, I would expect that after the COMMIT has succeeded, a read operation then starting in response should see the effects of that write.

My specific question is: Given two database client connections on different threads, is it possible for a race condition with one client viewing the effects of a write transaction AFTER the other client has committed? (no overlapping transactions).

Every bit of documentation I have found thus far only refers to concerns about overlapping/concurrent transaction and the MVCC/transaction isolation topics. Nothing about a synchronised serial operation between two different client connections.

Edit: Some extra details about the configuration.
ClientA and ClientB would be different threads accessing postgres through a connection pool. Clients may both be in the same connection pool on the same application server, or it may be ClientA/ApplicationA and ClientB/ApplicationB. 
When ClientB reacts, it will access the existing Application server connection pool to make a new read.

Comment: Could you provide more background on the nature of these two clients? Is there a connection pooler involved? When ClientB reacts, does it react by opening an new connection, opening a new transaction, continuing an existing transaction, or anything of that sort?

Comment: @richyen, I've updated the question with more details. Thanks! My question assumes the ClientB read is a completely new transaction, but can reuse an existing connection from a pool

Comment: If ClientB runs in `read committed` isolation level (the default) then yes, the change is immediately visible. If your code doesn't see the change, then maybe you are using `repeatable read` or `serializable`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name so you are saying that a non-overlapping read in another client may or may not immediately see the write commit, depending on the isolation level? Can you do a formal answer explaining this? It conflicts with the answer given by Laurenz, who says it cannot happen

Comment: @jdi: Laurenz' answer is saying the same thing

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name forgive me if I misinterpret, but your comment suggests that the change may not be immediately visible depending on the isolation level. Laurenz makes the distinction that it always visible if the read transaction starts after the write transaction, regardless of the isolation level.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, that cannot happen, unless the reading transaction started earlier and is running at the `REPEATABLE READ` or `SERIALIZABLE` isolation level.

There is also the possibility that the reading transaction does not connect to the same server as the writing transaction, but to a streaming replication standby server with `hot_standby` enabled. Then this can easily happen, even with synchronous replication (unless you set `synchronous_commit = remote_apply`).

Comment: I tried to simplify the case as much as possible, so this would be specifically about a single database, no replication, no overlapping transactions. Literally the read is started after the write commit transaction finishes, and the application server emits an external notification. This answer aligns with what I had thought to be true.

Comment: It is good to simplify the case, but in this case the problem must have been simplified away.

Comment: @jdi: Did you find an explanation for this behaviour? We have the same issue at the moment. Thread A writes and commits. Thread B (after A is finishes) attempts to read, but the data is not yet present in the DB. Thread B retries several times, and after ~2s the data is finally available. One DB instance, no replication, read committed isolation.

Comment: @AngryScientist no I never did get a concrete explanation other than the answers here.